# Как узнать имя компонента при вызове popup?

Tags: delphi, popupmenu

Есть форма на которой находится ряд кнопок. Ко всем кнопкам в инспекторе привязан один `PopupMenu`. В `PopupMenu` есть один пункт, при нажатии на который, должен меняться внешний вид кнопки, над которой это меню выпало. Как получить доступ к этому объекту?

Comment: К каому объекту ты хочешь получить доступ, к кнопке которая вызвала PopupMenu или к пункту меню PopupMenu?

Comment: (TButton)Senter должно работать.

Comment: Есть кнопка SpeedButton1 и кнопка SpeedButton2. Обе привязаны к PopupMenu1. http://cs625820.vk.me/v625820860/2c23a/2VRISiNzavE.jpg

Comment: Так вот. Нужно, чтобы при нажатии "По умолчанию" кнопка, на которой сделан клик становилась выпуклой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужен `popupmenu1.PopupComponent`